# SSH - How To Make Three Computer Tunnel?

Tags: ssh, networking, proxy, ssh-tunneling, socks

ComputerA connects though putty to Server at port 77, and there is a reverse tunnel set up from the Server at port 6666 to ComputerA at port 22. ComputerA also has a ssh server set up with a user account named ComputerA_user_name.

I can ssh from ComputerB into Server with the command `ssh admin@Server -p 9000 -D 6000`. Then I run a ruby program on my computer, ComputerB, which makes a socks proxy connection on port 6000 and it runs through Server. How do I make the ruby program connect through proxy from ComputerB to ComputerA?

What I am trying now is after I ssh in from ComputerB to Server runnng this command on Server `ssh -D 9000 localhost -p 6666 -l ComputerA_user_name` to bind from ComputerB to the Server, and then bind from Server to ComputerA but it gives me the message, `bind: Address already in use`.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

> SOCKS proxy via an Intermediate Host
>
> If you want to open a SOCKS proxy via an intermediate host, it is possible:
>
> `$ ssh -L 8001:localhost:8002 user1@machine1.example.org -t ssh -D 8002 user2@machine2.example.org`
>
> The client will see a SOCKS proxy on port 8001 on the local host, which is actually a connection to machine1 and traffic will ultimately enter and leave the net through machine2. Port 8001 on the local host connects to port 8002 on machine1 which is a SOCKS proxy to machine2. The port numbers can be chosen to be whatever you needed, but forwarding privileged ports still requires root privileges.

So in my case I used:

```
ssh -L 6000:localhost:6001 -p 9000 admin@ip
ssh -D 6001 -p 6666 localhost -l username -N
```