# rsync files between two remotes, with only access from the "intermediate"

Tags: rsync, ssh-tunneling, remote

**EDIT #1**

As per answer by roaima, I tried (here with `user1`=`user2`)

```
[user3@M3]$ ssh -R 50000:M2:22 user1@M1 rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" -avz /absolute_path1/ user2@localhost:/absolute_path2/
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
user2@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
```

There might be a problem with key pairs. There are 6 public-private keys that could be configured (M3->M1, etc.)

**Which of these are needed for the command to work (if any)?**

**Does any of the pairs need to be the same as any other?**

---

I have 3 machines, M1 (remote), M2 (at home), M3 (at home, behind the same router).
The possible ssh connections (Client->Server) are: M3->M1 (only via VPN), M3->M2. I use ssh key pairs in both cases.

1. M3 has no SSH server, so M1->M3 and M2->M3 are not possible.
2. I cannot use the VPN in M2, so M2->M1 is not possible.
3. I don't know if M1->M2 is possible.

I mean to rsync `user1@M1`->`user2@M2` (i.e., `user1@M1` as the source
and `user2@M2` as the target) and viceversa. In one particular case, `user1=user2`, but the general case is the target.

**Are they possible?**
**Only one of them?**
**How?**

**For that to be possible, is it mandatory to have M1->M2 access?**
**If so, how can I achieve this?**

I seem to be close to it.

1. Trying to rsync M1->M2, I executed in `user3@M3` (there is no `user1@M3` or `user2@M3`):

   ```
    [user3@M3]$ ssh -R localhost:50000:<M2 ip>:22 <M1 ip> 'rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" --perms -vur --dry-run <M1 dir> localhost:<M2 dir>'
    Enter passphrase for key '<user3 $HOME>/.ssh/id_rsa':
    Connection closed by <M1 ip> port 22
   ```

   Note that it is the agent in M3 that is asking for the key pair password (since `user3` only exists in `M3`) and I have entered it correctly.
2. Trying to rsync M2->M1, I executed in `user3@M3`:

   ```
    [user3@M3]$ ssh -R localhost:50000:<M1 ip>:22 <M2 ip> 'rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" --perms -vur --dry-run <M2 dir> localhost:<M1 dir>'
    Enter passphrase for key '<user2 $HOME>/.ssh/id_rsa':
    <user3>@<M2 ip>'s password:
    Permission denied, please try again.
    ...
   ```

   Note that user3 does not exist in M2, so that would never succeed.
   I have to find the correct way of passing user1. For this...
3. Trying to rsync M2->M1, I executed in `user3@M3` adding `user2`:

   ```
    [user3@M3]$ ssh -R localhost:50000:<M1 ip>:22 <user2>@<M2 ip> 'rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" --perms -vur --dry-run <M2 dir> localhost:<M1 dir>'
    Host key verification failed.
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
    rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
   ```

Note that using `user1` instead of `user2` or viceversa would not solve the problem, as they are the same here.

I would try perhaps being able to ssh M1->M2 or viceversa first, if that helps understanding how things work.

**How can I accomplish this?**

**Related:**

1. [How to rsync files between two remotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes)
2. [How to rsync files between two remote servers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432122/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remote-servers)
3. [Trying to run rsync between two remote servers via reverse port forwarding with ssh key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273437/trying-to-run-rsync-between-two-remote-servers-via-reverse-port-forwarding-with)
4. [How to rsync files between two remotes with an explicit port and different usernames?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284079/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes-with-an-explicit-port-and-different-usern)
5. [Aws ec2 - How to rsync files between two remotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375608/aws-ec2-how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes)
6. https://serverfault.com/questions/411552/rsync-remote-to-remote
7. https://serverfault.com/questions/249421/rsync-from-one-remote-to-another
8. https://superuser.com/questions/797473/creating-a-connection-between-3-computers
9. [SSH - How To Make Three Computer Tunnel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280915/ssh-how-to-make-three-computer-tunnel)

Comment: Your second sentence is confusing me. Generally one doesn't go from a Server to a Client; one starts on the Client (`ssh` or `rsync`) and connects to the Server (`sshd` or `rsyncd`). Can you clarify your question there, please

Comment: You could create a tunnel using `ssh -w ...`. This opens a new port which one can use to directly connect to the _more remote_ computer.

Comment: Reading your comment on [my rsync answer elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183516/100397) I think a lot of the confusion relates to "server" and "client". You seem to be using them backwards: the client connects to a server but in your question you seem to have a server trying to connect to a client.

Comment: @roaima - The notation I used to describe SSH connections might have been uncommon and thus confusing; I inverted it. Anyway, there was no ambiguity given that I defined the notation. Please check it now and confirm if you find it ok.
The notation I used for rsync was not changed, I only added now a definition for the notation, to be sure. Please check it now and confirm if you find it ok.
All this is but a matter of notation, nothing changes about what I would try as per your other answer. I think I have correctly identified the 4 "parameters" of your command: src/trg host + src/trg dir.

Comment: @roaima - If my configuration and my objective is now clear, could you please give your opinion (rather, knowledge!) about the specific questions?

Comment: @AlexisWilke - With all the specific information I have provided, would you mind posting the complete command/s to use?
Would you need any further data? Thanks!

Comment: I've not created an SSH tunnel in ages... I think symcbean has the right command line. You just have to fiddle with it. The port (2222 in his example) is the port you need rsync to connect to (instead of the default).

Answer (score 2):

> M3 has no SSH server, so M3->M1 and M3->M2 are not possible.

eh? It is the client which initiates the connection so I would generally write the relationship as client->server.

If there is no server in the middle then the obvious thing to try is to run rsync in the middle on M3 with a remote src and a remote dest (did you?). Unfortunately rsync can't cope with both ends remote. But you can set up a tunnel from M3 connecting to with either end then point rsync at the tunnel from the other end...

```
userm3@m3 $ ssh -L 2222:m2:22 userm2@m2
```

Then you can access m2 from m1 via m3:

```
userm1@m1 $ ssh -p 2222 userm2@m3
```

(but your authorized keys and any host specific keypairs will be confused by this)

Comment: 1) Please see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679101/rsync-files-between-two-remotes-with-only-access-from-the-intermediate#comment1282788_679101), I changed the notation.
2) What would the command that embodies " rsync in the middle on M3 with a remote src and a remote dest" be? If I understand you correctly, this is exactly what rsync cannot do.

Comment: I tried your commands #1 and #2. One thing that confused me about #2 is that `userm2@m3` does not exist.
In addition #2 keeps me waiting with no response at all, no messages, nothing.
I tried other combinations user/host in you commands, none worked.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try and pick the bones out of this

Three machines

- M1, remote, user1
- M2, home LAN, user2
- M3, home LAN, user3

Connections

- M3 can reach M1
- M3 can reach M2

You want to transfer data from M1 to M2, and possibly back again.

I assume that although M2 is also on the home LAN, it cannot reach M3. Since you want to use `rsync` to transfer data between M1 and M2 I shall assume that it's installed on both systems.

The obvious attempt is from M2, `rsync user1@M1: user2@M2:`, but this isn't possible (`rsync` can currently handle only one distinct remote target).

We can now map this directly to another question here on StackExchange, [How to rsync files between two remotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183504/100397), which asks how to implement

> ```
> rsync -vuar host1:/var/www host2:/var/www
> ```

[My answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183516/100397) given there offers this solution:

> ```
> ssh -R localhost:50000:host2:22 host1 'rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" -vuar /var/www localhost:/var/www'
> ```

And this in turn can be mapped back to your scenario by replacing `host1` with `M1` and `host2` with `M2`. Run this command on M3, which is the system that can reach both remote systems:

```
ssh -R localhost:50000:M2:22 user1@M1 rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" -avz /source/path/on/M1/ user2@localhost:/target/path/on/M2
```

You connect with `ssh` from `M3` to `user1@M1`. The connection establishes a channel from `M1`'s TCP/IP port 50000 to port 22 on machine `M2`, via the originating machine, `M3`. You then execute an `rsync` command that uses this channel to connect "directly" to M2. (I've changed the flags slightly; `rsync -avz` is a better default set than that used in the original question.)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer.
I edited the question with feedback (top posted). I adapted slightly the notation to allow for 3 different users, one per machine, as you wrote. This doesn't change any of the results.

Comment: Let's break the command out. Does this work from M3? If not it needs to be addressed first of all - `ssh -R 50000:M2:22 user1@M1`

Comment: I executed the ssh command with `-v`.
I also inspected `/var/log/auth.log`.
All this provided useful info. Will post ASAP.